# Download a html document from a website in pdf format

Tags: browser, pdf

**Can anybody please tell me how to download a webpage of [Times of India archives](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/archive.cms) in PDF format?**

Comment: @user3049087 Copy the address of the page you want to convert,then go to Pdfcrowd.com,paste the url and click "Convert to Pdf".Please reply if it works or not.

Comment: i want full web page instead articles

Comment: in pdc crowd i get log in page pdf instead actual page, as this web page is very fussy/non cooperative with other softwares, doesnt work

Comment: pls help me awaiting your response

Comment: the content is more probably hidden in web page as it is available in low resolution image so printing the page wont help as it will be blurry, but the provider provides the same page in small articles itself those are very clear and printable,this concludes it is embedded

Comment: dear friends printing may not help,"hidden in low resolution images"

Comment: Can any body solve this ?

Comment: ALL DEAR FRIENDS COULD YOU PLEASE SUGGEST ME ANY FORUM WHERE I CAN GET QUICK ANSWER TO THIS QUERRY ?

Answer (score 0):

If the webserver itslef does not provide PDF, you can not download it in that format. You would need to print, on your own side, the webpage, choosing the option "Print to file".

Comment: low resolution images

Answer (score 0):

You can try add-ons to do that

For Firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-pages-to-pdf/

For Chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-as-pdf/kpdjmbiefanbdgnkcikhllpmjnnllbbc?hl=en

Comment: My dear friend, printing may not help,"hidden in low resolution images"

Comment: u can check out deccan herald instead man, it gives out every article in pdf format

Comment: ALL DEAR FRIENDS COULD YOU PLEASE SUGGEST ME ANY FORUM WHERE I CAN GET QUICK ANSWER TO THIS QUERRY ?